# Cannot import import io.qameta.allure.Step;

Tags: java, maven, automated-tests, allure

I have got problems with importing

```
import io.qameta.allure.Allure; 
import io.qameta.allure.Step;
```

Allure and Step cannot be resolved. Maybe someone can tell me what is the reason. I am using maven and my pom.xml is:

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>untitled</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>Archetype - untitled</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
    <aspectj.version>1.8.10</aspectj.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
      <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
      <version>3.12.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
      <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
      <version>7.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
      <version>6.1.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
      <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
      <version>4.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
      <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
      <version>4.5.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
      <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
      <version>3.36.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
      <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
      <version>4.4.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
      <artifactId>allure-testng</artifactId>
      <version>2.22.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
      <artifactId>allure-junit5</artifactId>
      <version>2.22.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
      <version>5.8.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
      <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.json</groupId>
      <artifactId>json</artifactId>
      <version>20210307</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.32</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.32</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
      <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
      <version>3.21.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>9</source>
          <target>9</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.0</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
        <configuration>
          <testSourceDirectory>src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

What do i need to change to make it working. Because i can't cope with it my myself

What do i need to change to make it working. Because i can't cope with it my myself

What do i need to change to make it working. Because i can't cope with it my myself

What do i need to change to make it working. Because i can't cope with it my myself

What do i need to change to make it working. Because i can't cope with it my myself

Comment: Are you trying to import Allure in the test sources, or main?

Comment: in my class in src/main/java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Allure library is intended to be a test dependency, not a source/main dependency. The same goes for your project: both `allure-testng` and `allure-junit5` are in the test scope, meaning they're only available for classes inside `src/test/java`, and that's why you see the error.

If you really need to use it inside your sources, you may consider removing the `<scope>test</scope>` from your pom (not really recommended), but I guess you might want to move your logic into `src/test/java`, and import those testing libraries right there.